# Prior probability of unknown variance

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, laplace-distribution

Within my sampler I have to define the prior probability of the variance $\sigma$ of a random variable (drawn from $N(0,\sigma)$)

Here I assume that $\sigma$ is close to zero. Its distribution is expected as Laplace distributed but only with positive values (because it is a variance). Is there a similar distribution in $\mathbb{R}^+$ (only)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the Laplace distribution has the density 
$$f(x)=\frac{\lambda}{2}\exp\{-\lambda |x|\}$$
the positive restriction (rather than truncation) has density
$$f(x)=\lambda\exp\{-\lambda x\}\mathbb{I}_{\mathbb{R}^+}(x)$$
an exponential density, which explains why the Laplace distribution is also called the *double exponential distribution*.